# Drush site-upgrade target database

Tags: drush, upgrading

When using the drush site-upgrade (drush sup) to do a D6 to D7 upgrade, does the target database need to be pre-filled with D6 tables? Or can it be completely empty?

Thanks

Comment: assuming you're trying this on a test copy - what happens if it's completely empty?  There's really only one sensible way to find out....

Comment: i am on a test copy yes. and i setup a separate db on a different server and i was having alot of problems with missing tables. so far i am running an upgrade with an empty target db on the same db server as the source, hasn't crapped out yet...